# How to start material 3 compose project forked from official androix repository

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, open-source

I just wanna try to contributing to open source world i see in github that android has androidx source code for material3 i wanna contribute to it

but how to start that project in android studio, i mean how to run that forked library to my local machine, i wanna live preview of it library, mean is try to use that library

here is the material3 compose component

[image]

[here is the source code of it](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/tree/androidx-main/compose/material3/material3)

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Contribution Guide](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/docs/onboarding.md) in the repository. 
 There are detailed instructions on how to get the project set up locally and how to contribute. 
 Note that currently, development seems only to be supported for Mac and Linux, **not for Windows**. Also, pull reguests only are accepted for a [few libraries](https://github.com/androidx/androidx?tab=readme-ov-file#contribution-guide), **not including material3**.

You will have to install a repo tool, which has similar capabilities like Git. Also, you will install a specific version of Android Studio for library development. 
The guide also explains how to [get the Previews working](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/docs/onboarding.md#enabling-compose-preview-annotation-previews).

If you only want to inspect some code, you could try to simply clone the repository in Android Studio like this:

`Android Studio -> New Project -> Import existing project from Version Control`

Then enter the URL from the `Code` button in Github in Android Studio:

[image: github code]